# Python Pandas: Conditional Updating of Column Values Based on Another Col ('int' object is not subscriptable) error

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have the following sample data frame.  col_2 is an integer datatype

```
col_1                 col_2
(hello, you, good)    65
(yes, are, tiles)     23
```

I want my code to replace the value in col_2 if col_1 contains a certain string.  Otherwise, leave col_2 value as is.

Below is my code:

```
df['col_3'] = np.where(df['col_1'] == '(hello, you, good)', 18, df['col_2'])
```

Below is my desired output:

```
col_1                 col_2
(hello, you, good)    18
(yes, are, tiles)     23
```

But when I run my code above, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Your code works for this sample (except it should be `df['col_2']`). Can you make it such that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: you are right; I made the col name edit

Comment: Your code still works for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is not string type column for `col_1`

```
np.where(df['col_1'] == ('hello', 'you', 'good'), 18, df['col_2'])  
Out[759]: array([18, 23], dtype=int64)
```